# Is using the focus() method in JS considered DOM manipulation?

Tags: javascript, dom, dom-manipulation

I'm just wondering since I don't know if adding focus to an element is considered changing the DOM.

example:

`document.querySelector('button').focus()`

Why does it matter?
I was reading some angular documentation, and there are two API I am looking to use to access the DOM but one of them has a caution against using it when manipulating the DOM because of possible vulnerabilities to XSS attacks. So I wanted to know if it would be safe to use `.focus()` with the `ElementRef` Class.

Here are the definitions of he two classes from Angular docs.

*The `Renderer` is a class that is a partial abstraction over the DOM. Using the Renderer for manipulating the DOM doesn't break server-side rendering or Web Workers (where direct access to the DOM would break).*

*`ElementRef` is a class that can hold a reference to a DOM element. This is again an abstraction to not break in environments where the browsers DOM isn't actually available.*

Comment: I don't think so. Why does it matter?

Comment: I do think so. Why does it matter?

Comment: @Barmar Why do you think it isn't?

Comment: I guess it depends on what you mean by "changing the DOM". It doesn't change any DOM structure or attribute that might show up in `innerHTML`, it's transient state like `.value`.

Comment: I see it as like saying "stand here" or "look here" in a room - you're not changing the room (DOM) itself, but moving yourself or your attention within that room. But again, why does changing the DOM matter?

Answer (score 2):

Yes of course, the [`focus()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/focus) does manipulate the state of the DOM. It might not manipulate the document's node tree structure, but it still affects the document. In particular, apart from firing `change`, `blur` and `focus` events, it does change the [`document.activeElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/activeElement) property.

> I wanted to know if it would be safe to use `.focus()` with the `ElementRef` Class.

Yes, there is no XSS risk for `.focus()`.